# Calculating the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n-1)!}x^n$?

Tags: summation, power-series

So I've got the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n-1)!}x^n$$

To show that it converges for all real numbers, I used the ratio test. And found the convergence radius to be $$R = \frac{1}{L}, \qquad R = \infty$$
The next task is to calculate the sum, and I feel sort of lost.. I think I want the sum too look like a geometric series. Or substitute it with something else.

Comment: Write $n = (n-1) + 1$ in the numerator.

Comment: $x\left(x + 1\right)\,\mathrm{e}^{x}$ is the answer. There are three incomplete answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
**First way**. Note that
$$xe^x=x(e^x)'=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{(n-1)!}.$$
Try to differentiate again and compare the result with your series.

**Second way**. we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n-1)!}x^n=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m+1}{m!}x^{m+1}=x^2\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m}{m!}x^{m-1}+x\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^{m}}{m!}.$$
What then?

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, you have do differentiate to remove the first element in the series. But why do I have to do it twice? 
$$x(e^x)' = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}$$
That looks good to me?

Comment: @Viktor Because you need a factor $n$ multiplying $x$. You can also follow the alternative way (where no differentiation is needed).

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use $n=(n-1)+1$ and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{x}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{n}}{n!}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}}$$
or
$$xe^{x}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{n}}{(n-1)!}}$$